# How come my verticle square bar on my website wont show up?

Tags: html, css

I tried to add a verticle bar thats stuck to the top right off my screen but it dosent show up for some reason, i tried everything i could. here is my code.
css: used for the style of my site, just uhh regular old code expect that it show anything thats located at the bottom of my website expressed by the overflow hidden thing. Anyways inspect element tells me that my gradient bar is at the bottom of the site even though its not supposed to be. see last couple lines of the css code for the bar.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0c7bcb; /* change to desired color */
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1ch;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
    padding-top: 0.5px;
    font-size: small;
    border-color: rgba(12, 123, 203, 0.5); /* half transparent #0c7bcb color */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: aliceblue;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #0c7bcb;
    background-image: url("https://www.minecraft.net/etc.clientlibs/minecraft/clientlibs/main/resources/favicon.ico");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 30px; /* adjust as needed to make room for the icon */
    border-bottom-width: 0.5px;
    border-top-width: 0.5px;
    background-size: 20px 20px; /* adjust the size as needed */
}
.Texty {
    
}

#close-button {
    padding-top: 1px;
    color: aliceblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.updates {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-color: aliceblue;
    color: #2bab10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    right: 300px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: 'main';
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 6in;
    }
.back {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/694661573125472256/1070884589108744192/image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#baro {
    background-color: #78ac4c;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #play-btn {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: main;
    src: url(font.ttf);
  }


.discord ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
.dickkord ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #0c7bcb; /* change to desired color */
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1ch;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
    padding-top: 0.5px;
    font-size: small;
    border-color: rgba(12, 123, 203, 0.5); /* half transparent #0c7bcb color */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: aliceblue;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #0c7bcb;
    background-image: url("https://www.minecraft.net/etc.clientlibs/minecraft/clientlibs/main/resources/favicon.ico");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 30px; /* adjust as needed to make room for the icon */
    border-bottom-width: 0.5px;
    border-top-width: 0.5px;
    background-size: 20px 20px; /* adjust the size as needed */
}
.Texty {
    
}

#close-button {
    padding-top: 1px;
    color: aliceblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.updates {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-color: aliceblue;
    color: #2bab10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 135px;
    right: 300px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: 'main';
    width: 1000px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 6in;
    }
.back {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/694661573125472256/1070884589108744192/image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#baro {
    background-color: #78ac4c;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #play-btn {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: main;
    src: url(font.ttf);
  }


.discord ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
.dickkord ul {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#gradient-bar {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000, #ffffff);
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Eaglercraft.xyz</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="bar">
        <p>
            Eaglercraft.xyz Launcher
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="close-button">&times;</div>
    <div class="back">
        <pi></pi>
    </div>
    <div id="gradient-bar">
        <p>aaseasea</p>
    </div>
<div class="updates">
    <div class="Texty">
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Be sure to join our discord!</p>
    <div class="discord">
        <ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Stay up to date with the latest news, contests, giveaways and other cool things: discord.gg :)</ul>
    </div>
<div class"dickkord">
<p style="color: #298bc4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Minecraft 1.8</p>
<ul style="color: black;"></ulstyle>Diorite: Crafted using 2 cobblestone and 2 Nether quartz in a checkerboard pattern.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Andesite: Crafted using 1 cobblestone and 1 diorite.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Granite: Crafted using 1 Nether quartz and 1 diorite.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Coarse Dirt: Replaces grassless dirt found in mega taiga, mesa and savanna biomes. It is slightly darker than regular dirt. Tilling it with a hoe turns it to regular dirt. Can be crafted using dirt and gravel in a 2x2 checkered pattern.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Prismarine: Generates in ocean monuments and can be crafted using prismarine shards. Cracks in prismarine slowly change color.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Prismarine Bricks: Generates in ocean monuments and can be crafted using prismarine shards.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Dark Prismarine: Generates in ocean monuments and can be crafted using prismarine shards and an ink sac.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Red Sandstone: Can be crafted using 4 red sand in a square. Comes in chiseled, smooth, stair, and slab forms. Generated only in Mesa biomes at cave entrances.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Iron Trapdoor: Can only be opened and closed using redstone. Crafted using iron ingots in a 2x2 pattern.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Sea Lantern: Generates in ocean monuments and can be crafted using prismarine shards and prismarine crystals. Emits light and has an animated texture.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Wet Sponge: Obtained when a sponge soaks up water. Smelting yields a dry sponge. Emits water dripping particles. Dropped by elder guardians.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Slime Block: Crafted using 9 slime balls. Players and mobs bouncing on top. Pushes and pulls blocks when moved by a piston. Does not affect falling items.</ul>
<ul style="color: black; font-weight: 100;"></ulstyle>Banners: Crafted like signs but using wool. Can be stacked to 16 and have up to 6 layers. Can be placed on walls or on the ground. Different patterns can be made using dyes and certain items.</ul>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="baro">
    <select id="menu1">
      <option selected value="latest">Latest Releases</option>
      <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
      <option value="1.8">1.8</option>
    </select>
    <select id="menu2" style="display: none;">
    </select>
    <button id="play-button" style="background-color: #f0c43c; border-radius: 20%; align-content: center;">Play</button>
  </div>
  
  

  <script src="epic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start with a [**Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

**Reasoning:**
Due to the 'back' class div set to the height of '100vh' *(Vertical Height)*, The following div with static positioning will sit just below the div with the class of 'back'

**Solution:**
Rearranging your code makes it visible just under the blue bar

```
<div class="bar">
    <p>
        Eaglercraft.xyz Launcher
    </p>
</div>
<div id="close-button">&times;</div>
<div id="gradient-bar">
    <p>aaseasea</p>
</div>
<div class="back">
    <pi></pi>
</div>
```

To put it in the very top of the page I used the following
**HTML:**

```
<div id="gradient-bar">
    <p>aaseasea</p>
</div>
<div class="bar">
    <div id="close-button" style="top: 20px">&times;</div>
    <!-- style attr to fix the cross -->
    <p>
        Eaglercraft.xyz Launcher
    </p>
</div>
<div class="back">
    <pi></pi>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#gradient-bar p {
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

And to half it you could set #gradient-bar width to 50%
And to put it in the top right corner you could put

```
#gradient-bar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Hoped I helped in some way!